# 7zip how to copy file from zip to another zip

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, copy, files-folders

In 7zip with 2 panel view, I have 2 different zips open on both sides. I can drag and drop one file from inside the zip on the left side inside the right hand side zip file but it only preserves the date modified. Is there a command line syntax to copy from zip to zip while also preserving the timestamps dc dm da ? I know in 7zip cmd line there is -mtc and -mta switch

Comment: i did not understand can you give an example ?

Comment: Relevant, possible solution: https://github.com/aonez/Keka/issues/398

Comment: 7Zip probably copied the file by extracting it to a temporary folder, then importing to the other window. Try to do it yourself, extracting manually the file in the one side, then importing on the other, while checking at every step. This will tell if there is a problem with the extract, or the import, or the combined operation. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: That github topic resulted in nothing being solved and the tc tm ta switch is for when creating new archives with 7zip only

Comment: I am surprised that there is no documentation in command line way of copying within zip files =(

Comment: @harrymc You are correct in the sense that 7zip creates a temporary folder with random characters and inside of it, the actual folder to be copied exists there with the correct timestamps. When the copy process is complete from 7zip, only then does the folder disappear within temp folder and only the date modified is retained within the destination zip. Is there a way to change this behavior so that timestamps are preserved?

Comment: First, are timestamps preserved in that folder? Are they preserved when extracting manually?

Comment: inside the temporary folder they are preserved in windows temporary. When extracting the folder manually, the timestamps dc dm da are preserved

I did not test when extracting from zip and then adding to the other zip with 7zip

Comment: When extracting the folder from one archive to the C drive then copying that folder to the destination zip, does not preserve the dc or da timestamps